# Nested Link component in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a post card, which if clicked brings you to the post's page, i also have a link inside the post card which when clicked brings you to the album of posts the post is from.

The code structure is similar to this one:

```
<Link href={post.url} className={styles.post}>
    ...title and stuff
    <Link href={post.groupUrl}>
        {post.group}
    </Link>
</Link>
```

It worked before updating to Nextjs 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is less of a Next.js bug because, at the end, the `Link` component is just a fancy `a` tag and also gets rendered as one in the DOM. And, as you can read [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2), nesting links is illegal.